# How can I convert this TPL or PHP condition to a valid condition?

Tags: twig

I would like to add a condition to my twig file, but I can only find code examples for TPL or PHP. All my attempts to translate this into twig syntax have so far been unsuccessful. This may also be due to the fact that these examples are no longer up-to-date. Unfortunately, there is little current information about the open source vanilla forum. But as long as I don't even know if my twig syntax should actually work, I can't say that.

Can someone please help me and tell me if my twig syntax is correct?

Thank you for help!

This is what the relevant part of my twig looks like (I only want to display the main panel for Signed In users):

```
 <div class="Frame-details">
    {% if not isHomepage %}
        <div class="Frame-row">
            <nav class="BreadcrumbsBox" aria-label={{ t("Breadcrumb") }}>
                {{ renderBreadcrumbs() }}
            </nav>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="Frame-row">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <section class="Content MainContent">
            {{ renderControllerAsset("Content") }}
        </section>
        <!-- Main Content END -->
        <!-- Main Panel -->
        
        {% if UserSignedIn %}
        <div class="Panel Panel-main">
            {{ renderControllerAsset("Panel") }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <!-- Main Panel END -->
```

Here are the examples I've found so far:

```
For TPL is the following example:

{if $User.SignedIn}
Do some coding like show the Panel Asset
{/if}

For PHP is the following example:

$Session = Gdn::Session();
if ($Session->IsValid())
{
Show the Panel Asset
} else
{
Show only the Guest Box asset
```

Comment: What is not working here? You can just pass the `user` and/or `session` instance to your template from your controller

Comment: Thank you! My problem is that I don't really understand the complete concept of vanilla and I don't even know which of the many controllers is rendering this twig. I also thought that the 'user' should already be available there because the examples are from the vanilla forum (but they are the only ones and very old). In any case, nobody had explicitly pointed out that the controller first had to be passed on. But of course that may be why nothing I'm trying to do is having any effect. I thought maybe it's my twig syntax. Can one use 'User.SignedIn' in twig (with dot) to get $User.SignedIn!?

Comment: You can find what the [dot]-notation actually does in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables). Are you using twig standalone or with a framework e.g. symfony?

Comment: Thanks for the link, that really helps a lot. I'm trying to customize my open source version of the vanilla forums and that's the last thing missing. But I've never done anything with Twig or Laravel. That's why I have to understand this little by little. 
The twig here is the layout.default.twig of the template used.